# Unknown column in where clause. Why?

Tags: mysql, select, field, where-clause

I use next query:

```
SELECT ROUND(r/h) AS conv FROM table WHERE conv > 1
```

I receive error `"Unknown column 'conv' in 'where clause'"`, But why? After `AS conv` is it not exists yet?

Comment: @Bob's answer shows correct approach, through you may like to try: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROUND(r/h) AS conv FROM table) as t1  WHERE conv > 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column alias isn't available until results are being produced. Try

```
SELECT ROUND(R / H) AS CONV
  FROM TABLE1
  WHERE ROUND(R / H) > 1
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0792b/4).

Share and enjoy.

Comment: After reading your answer, my answer looks Jok.